# is it possible to transfer trained tesseract

Tags: tesseract

Does the simple way to transfer trained tesseract from one system to another exist? Is it transportable or I need to retrain it on every new computer which uses my application?

Thank you very much for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `.traineddata` files are platform-independent. They should work on any system that Tesseract runs on.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to transfer `.traineddata` file